# css slider shows only first 3 images

Tags: html, css, image, slider

I found a nice and simple automatic css slider (http://dreyacosta.github.io/pure-responsive-css3-slider/) but the problem is it shows only first 3 images one by one and then repeats them. How can I make it slide all images regardless how many I put in the list? Each image is 300px by 225px and I also want to keep its aspect ration regardless of a screen size.

```css
.card-img-top {
height:auto;
width:100%;
display:block;
border-top-left-radius:calc(.25rem - 1px);
border-top-right-radius:calc(.25rem - 1px)
}

.slider {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slider ol {
  width: 1000%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  list-style: none;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  -moz-animation:slide-animation 10s infinite;
  -webkit-animation:slide-animation 10s infinite;
}

.slider ol:hover {
  -moz-animation-play-state:paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
}

.slider li {
  width: 10%;  
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-animation {
  1% {left: 0%; opacity: 1;}
  18% {left: 0%; opacity: 1}
  19% {opacity: 0.2;}
  20% {left: -100%; opacity: 1;}
  58% {left: -100%; opacity: 1;}
  59% {opacity: 0.2;}
  60% {left: -200%; opacity: 1;}
  98% {left: -200%; opacity: 1;}
  99% {opacity: 0.5;}
  100% {left: 0%;}
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-animation {
  1% {left: 0%; opacity: 1;}
  18% {left: 0%; opacity: 1}
  19% {opacity: 0.2;}
  20% {left: -100%; opacity: 1;}
  58% {left: -100%; opacity: 1;}
  59% {opacity: 0.2;}
  60% {left: -200%; opacity: 1;}
  98% {left: -200%; opacity: 1;}
  99% {opacity: 0.5;}
  100% {left: 0%;}
}
```

```html
<!-- Slideshow box -->
 <div class="slider">
<ol>
<li><img src="http://www.maggitekstils.lv/img/pillowcases.jpg" class="card-img-top"></li>
<li><img src="http://www.maggitekstils.lv/img/pillowcases-curly-light.jpg" class="card-img-top"></li>
<li><img src="http://www.maggitekstils.lv/img/pillowcases-circles-pink.jpg" class="card-img-top"></li>
<li><img src="http://www.maggitekstils.lv/img/pillowcases-khaki.jpg" class="card-img-top"></li>
<li><img src="http://www.maggitekstils.lv/img/pillowcases-circles-blue.jpg" class="card-img-top"></li>
<li><img src="http://www.maggitekstils.lv/img/pillowcases-pink-violet.jpg" class="card-img-top"></li>
<li><img src="http://www.maggitekstils.lv/img/pillowcases-red-poppy.jpg" class="card-img-top"></li>
<li><img src="http://www.maggitekstils.lv/img/pillowcases-cacao.jpg" class="card-img-top"></li>
</ol>
</div>
<!--end-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a great slider tbh, but the 3 image limit is set through `left`:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide-animation {
  1% {left: 0%; opacity: 1;} // Slideshow is 0% to the left
  18% {left: 0%; opacity: 1}
  19% {opacity: 0.2;}
  20% {left: -100%; opacity: 1;} // Slideshow is 100% to the left, so showing slide 2
  58% {left: -100%; opacity: 1;}
  59% {opacity: 0.2;}
  60% {left: -200%; opacity: 1;} // Slideshow is 200% to the left, showing slide 3
  98% {left: -200%; opacity: 1;}
  99% {opacity: 0.5;}
  100% {left: 0%;} // Slideshow is 0% to the left - back to start
}
```

You'd need to split into smaller increments to add -300% for slide 4, -400% for slide 5 etc.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for sliders for days. Can you suggest a better one? I don't need anything too fancy or complicated.

Comment: look at this in the past in stack overlow I answered to one user @enars https://jsfiddle.net/nz9564ak/

Comment: It really depends what you want to do with it - but this one seems hard to manage to me - say you want to take an image out, then you need to refactor all your keyframes! It's hard to make recommendations as I don't know your level or your intentions, but personally I would learn a framework like https://materializecss.com/ - it has a slider built in (though it is JS based). For me, if I need extra functionality, I go to https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I just found another good option https://swiperjs.com/demos/